# Count Rows Under Within Specific Ranges

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
Server        AvgValue
Server1       1.29          
Server2       0.2           
Server3       1.74        
Server4       0.58          
Server5       2.06         
Server6       2.82
```

I'd like to show the count of servers that have an:

1. AvgValue < 10
2. AvgValue > 10 and < 30
3. AvgValue > 30 and < 50
4. AvgValue > 50 and < 80
5. AvgValue > 80

Any suggestions?

---

Alberto has provided the best option so far, and does answer my original question. I am however running into cases where the server is listed multiple times, and I'd like to average the AvgValue and make sure the server is only counted once in the range. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far.    Also, what RDMS, SQL-Server?   MySql, Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most simple approach is to use a query like this:

```
SELECT Server, COUNT(*) AS ServersCount
FROM ServersTable
WHERE AvgValue < 10
GROUP BY Server
```

You didn't mention anything about the RDBMS that you're using. If you're using MySQL, check the documentation about [COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html).

This query has to be modified for each condition. Then, you will have to execute five different queries.

Otherwise, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT ServersWithAvgValueLT10 = SUM(CASE WHEN AvgValue < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       ServersWithAvgValueGT10LT30 = SUM(CASE WHEN AvgValue > 10 AND AvgValue < 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       ServersWithAvgValueGT30LT50 = SUM(CASE WHEN AvgValue > 30 AND AvgValue < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       ServersWithAvgValueGT50LT80 = SUM(CASE WHEN AvgValue > 50 AND AvgValue < 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       ServersWithAvgValueGT80 = SUM(CASE WHEN AvgValue > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
FROM ServersTable
```

The result is achieved using the [SUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function and [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query like

```
select server,
count(Server) as NUmber_Of_Server,
sum(floor(AvgValue)) as Avg_Score
from tab group by Server
```

See a demo fiddle here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e05e/5

Answer (score 0):

**In a SQL server, we can do it like this -**

```
DECLARE @lowerLimit int
DECLARE @upperLimit int
SET @lowerLimit = 0
SET @upperLimit = 1
SELECT 
[Server]
,[AvgValue]
FROM [Services]
WHERE ([AvgValue] < @upperLimit
AND [AvgValue] > @lowerLimit)
```

**Here is the query to create a sample table for SQL server -**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Services](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Server] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [AvgValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[Services] ([Id], [Server], [AvgValue]) 
VALUES (1, N'Server1', CAST(1.29 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Services] ([Id], [Server], [AvgValue]) 
VALUES (2, N'Server2', CAST(0.20 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Services] ([Id], [Server], [AvgValue]) 
VALUES (3, N'Server3', CAST(1.74 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Services] ([Id], [Server], [AvgValue]) 
VALUES (4, N'Server4', CAST(0.58 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Services] ([Id], [Server], [AvgValue]) 
VALUES (5, N'Server5', CAST(2.06 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Services] ([Id], [Server], [AvgValue]) 
VALUES (6, N'Server6', CAST(2.82 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
```